# How can I find all the possible combinations of a list of lists (in Python)?

Tags: python

I have the following structure in Python:

```
letters = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

I would like to find all the possible combinations of letters in the order that they currently exist. For the example above this would be:

```
apj
apk
apl
aqj
aqk
aql
...
csk
csl
```

This seems like it should be a very simple thing to do but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Can we assume that the values are already ordered within the individual lists?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @wcm: No, the values in the individual lists are not ordered.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990003/how-can-i-find-all-the-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: @Tamas: Thats a link to this question.

Comment: whoops, wrong link, I meant this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Python 2.6 or newer you can use [**`itertools.product`**](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> map(''.join, itertools.product(*letters))
apj
apk
apl
aqj
aqk
aql
...etc...
csk
csl
```

Comment: And in older Pythons, you can copy the pure Python implementation of `product` from the `itertools` docs.